Not able to use Input of type of Range with Datalist in React Project Intergrated with Tailwind & Daisy UI CSS
I am working with React, i wanted to use range for some sort of rating purpose but when i use input of type range with datalist, it does not show me range placeholder below. I tried everything but still not working for me.

Exprected Output



Final Output


<input type="range" min={0} max="10" list="tickmarks" className="range mb-3" step="0.5"/>
<datalist id="tickmarks">
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="3"></option>
<option value="4"></option>
<option value="5"></option>
<option value="6"></option>
<option value="7"></option>
<option value="8"></option>
<option value="9"></option>
</datalist>

I want also to show a tick mark below my range for better ui purpose.

Your code as such copied below worked here. Please confirm it with the test results enclosed.
App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={0}
        max="10"
        list="tickmarks"
        className="range mb-3"
        step="0.5"
      />
      <datalist id="tickmarks">
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2"></option>
        <option value="3"></option>
        <option value="4"></option>
        <option value="5"></option>
        <option value="6"></option>
        <option value="7"></option>
        <option value="8"></option>
        <option value="9"></option>
      </datalist>
    </>
  );
}

Test run
In Goggle Chrome

In Mozilla FireFox


I am also using tailwind css and daisyui, Please try after installing these packages.

Hi, I shall try so. This case is quite common in styling, especially when CSS libraries or frameworks are used. The style finally applied to an element in the Browser may require  some adjustments. The HTML Element INSPECT option in Developer Tools in Google Chrome, for instance, would help. You can inspect the style using it and find out the rule which making the issue. Once you have spotted the exact rule(s) breaking the expected results, you may please override it. As you know, the inline style has the highest priority, therefore you can override rule by applying inline styles.

There are few more ways to override styles which you can see it on the Web. By the way, the following video may give some guidance on using Inspect https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb6ZIlYj2OY

Already tried developer options but nothing help.

By using Inspect, please disable all styles for this element alone and see the effect, it would definitely work. It is the way to handle such cases.
